# How do I set the current page for a global navigation cfm in ColdFusion Model Glue 3?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, model-glue

I have a **navigation.cfm** page that I'm including in all of my pages by using a MG3 custom event type:

```
<event-type name="pageWithNav">
    <after>
        <views>
            <include name="navigation" template="templates/navigation.cfm"/>
            <include name="maintemplate" template="templates/main.cfm"/>
        </views>
    </after>
</event-type>
```

And I'm using it in an event handler like so:

```
<event-handler name="page.home" type="pageWithNav">
    <views>
        <include name="body" template="pages/home.cfm"/>
    </views>
</event-handler>
```

My question is, how do I set a variable so that the **navigation.cfm** page knows what the current page is? So far I've done the following in the `page.home` event handler:

```
<include name="body" template="pages/home.cfm">
    <value name="currentPage" value="home"/>
</include>
```

By setting the value like this, it becomes available to all views that come after it. Although this works, the semantics is wrong because it looks like the `currentPage` variable is used by the **home.cfm** template instead of **navigation.cfm**. What would be the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the best practice is but you could consider setting a value in the viewstate from within the primary view that can be picked up the `after` views.

eg in the view pages/home.cfm use `<cfset viewState.setValue("currentPage","home") />`

and then in view templates/navigation.cfm use `<cfset viewState.getValue("currentPage","") />`

to retrieve it again.

I haven't tried this in the context of `after` event types but I do use this to set a `pagetitle` variable that the template uses to set the html `title` attribute.